# c# interface with multiple possible implementations

Tags: c#, interface

I am attempting to develop an interface to be used by different payment processor wrapper implementations, such as stripe, paypal, etc., that can be injected into another class.  The problem I am running into is that it is quite possible that each implementation may require different bits of data to process a payment thus making a common interface across implementations difficult.

Is this a scenario where it would make more sense to create an interface specific to each type of processor and design the receiving class to expect a specific interface? While this seems cleanest and keeps things testable it would require some re-development of the receiving class to implement a new processor.

I'd like to avoid creating empty interfaces or have an interface with methods for each type of processor and have each implementation throw not implemented exceptions on the methods it doesn't need.  The other option is to have common methods such as "ChargeCard" that accept an object, which would contain the data needed by each implementation but that doesn't feel right either.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Sounds too nebulous to get a proper answer.

Comment: Maybe through some higher level of abstraction You will be able to provide some common logic. If different bits of data are required by each processor, You can perform partial data processing inside the processor wrapper itself (parts that will be different in different processors) and then in the interface use some more generalized logic. This is only a suggestion, because I don't know what exactly You have already tried, but maybe it'll be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple patterns you can do:

- Visitor - pass in lowest common denominator. In other words everything that might ever be used and then let the processor figure it out.
- Mediator - Create a new object whole sole purpose is to figure out what a processor to use, and feed it what it needs.

And my favorite if you have the time is to take the two above and make them dynamic so that all you need to do is drop in a plug in that implements an interface and the framework will automatically pick it up and call it. for examples see the message handling in NServiceBus or Rebus. These frameworks take incoming messages of type IMessage and auto-magically feed them to message handlers. The common interface is like this:

```
public interface IMessageHandler<T> where T : IMessage
{
    void Handle(T message);
}
```

Unfortunately I have had to implement this a few times myself rather than just use the framework because I was not allowed to use it.

What approach you take depends on what you are working on - how often is it going to change, is it just a prototype or POC, etc.

Definitely avoid a large interface with methods that will not be used by all.

Adding some more info based on your comment, it would look something like this:

```
public interface IPaymentProcessor<T> where T : IPaymentInfo
{
    void ProcessPayment(T paymentInfo);
}

// Just one example

public class CreditCardPaymentInfo : IPaymentInfo
{
    public CardInfo CardInfo { get; set; }
}

public class CreditCardPaymentProcessor : IPaymentProcessor<CreditCardPaymentInfo>
{
    public void ProcessPayment(CreditCardPaymentInfo paymentInfo)
    {
        // Do the card processing here - you have what you need
    }
}
```

Then somewhere in your code payments are coming in, so it would call a method like this:

```
public void ProcessCardSwipe(CardData cardData)
{
    var cardInfo = new CreditCardPaymentInfo { CardInfo = cardData };

    ProcessPaymentInfo(cardInfo);
}

public void ProcessPaymentInfo(IPaymentInfo paymentInfo)
{
    // This should be refactored into a separate class, but initially to get it working this is fine
    if (paymentInfo is CreditCardPaymentInfo)
    {
        new CreditCardPaymentProcessor().Process((CreditCardPaymentInfo)paymentInfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: For the visitor pattern would this essentially have a common interface such as IPayments{void ChargeCard(ChargeCardCommand command);} and the ChargeCardCommand would contain both stripe and paypal properties?  Then the implementation would pick and choose the properties it was interested in?

Comment: You could do it a few ways. The ChargeCardCommand would have what that particular processor needs or maybe just some general purpose context object. Or maybe ChargeCardCommand<T> where T is specific to that type of command.

Comment: Thanks for the additional detail.  I think it might still get hung up on the CardInfo class.  Each processor might require different data in that class.  Stripe, for instance, only needs the amount and a token when charging a card, whereas pay pal might need a different set of information

Comment: CardInfo is specific to the implementation of IPaymentInfo for credit cards (CreditCardPaymentInfo). PayPal would have it's own implementation of IPaymentInfo and most likely have vastly different fields like email address, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is by using an abstract class as your intended parent in the assembly you use.

```
 IPaypal
 {
     //PayPal specific methods
 }

 IStripe
 {
     //Stripe specific methods
 }

 MyAbstractClass : IPaypal, IStripe //Other interfaces
 {
     //Method implementation for all of the inherited methods
 }


 MyPaymentClass : MyAbstractClass
 {
      //stuff
 }

 {
       var payment = new MyPaymentClass();
       payment.paypalMethod;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This sound it like  you could maybe use abstracts class to encapsulate the common behavior and extends to the other classes.
Another approach is create interface at high level, and subsequently create a low level interfaces which extends the high level interface then use for each class that you need it.

```
IPay{
 void chargetoCard();
}

 IStripe:IPay{
  chargetoStripe();
 }

  IAnother:IPay{
  void charge(); 
 }

 class Stripe:IStripe{
 }

 class Another:IAnother{
 }
```

Comment: I originally thought of creating a parent interface with some common functionality but struggled to find much in common other than perhaps a status property, which seemed pretty close to creating a marker interface.  Something like interface IPaymentProcessor{bool Status{get;set;}}  IStripe : IPaymentProcessor{string StripeProperty{get;set;}}